# How to find number of elements in a ring and a unit in the same ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given the quotient R = $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 2x^3+ x+1\rangle}$ ?
I have to find how many elements are in it and also if the polynomial 1+$x^2$+$x^4$ is a unit in R.

I know to prove a ring has a unit I have to show it has a multiplicative inverse but I'm not sure how to find the number of elements in the quotient. If I can show that the polynomial is irreducible then I think the number of elements is $7^3$=343 but I don't know how to show that it's irreducible on $Z_7[x]$

Comment: You don't need to prove  that the polynomial is irreducible. There is a canonical bijection between $R$ and the polynomials of degree $\le2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Its meant to be $Z_7$, fixed it now.  The degree of the polynomial is > 2 though? Or am I misunderstanding you

Comment: Any $[P]\in R$ has a (unique) representative of degree $\le2$: the remainder of the Euclidean division of $P$ by $2x^3+x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem**: Let $R$ be any commutative ring, and let $$f=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\in R[x]$$ Then $f$ is a unit $\iff a_0$ is a unit, and $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ are nilpotent.

*Proof*: ($\Leftarrow$) Let $$z=a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$$ Then $z$ is nilpotent. This follows by induction, since for any two nilpotents $a,b$ with $a^n=b^m=0$ we have $$(a+b)^{n+m}=\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{i}a^ib^{n+m-i}$$ Let therefore $z^k=0$. To show that $f=a_0+z$ is a unit, notice that $$\frac{1-(-a^{-1}_0z)^k}{1+a^{-1}_0z}=\frac{a_0}{a_0+z}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-a^{-1}_0z)^i$$ So $f$ is a unit.

($\Rightarrow$) Let $P\subset R$ be a prime ideal. And work over the quotient ring $(R/P)[x]$. This ring is an integral domain. Suppose that $f$ is a unit, then we may write $$1\equiv_P fg$$ Therefore $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in P$ since they vanish, and $a_0$ is a unit. This holds for every prime ideal $P$, therefore $$a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\bigcap_{P\subset R} P=\mathfrak N(R)$$ $\blacksquare$

We have $x^4+x^2+1\equiv_R 4x^2-4x+1$. Since $4$ is not a zero-divisor in $\Bbb Z_7$ we can't have $4x^2-4x+1$ a unit.

As pointed out in the comments every element in $R$ is on the form $ax^2+bx+c$, since $$2x^3+x+1\equiv_R 2(x^3+4x+4)\equiv_R 0\Rightarrow x^3\equiv_R 3x+3$$ so every polynomial of degree $\geq 3$ can be reduced to a polynomial of lower degree. Also, Kingdom Hearts is light!

Comment: I don't see how $4$ being a non-zero element leads to the conclusion that $4x^2-4x+1$ is a non-unit. One alternative approach that I can think of is to look at the ideal $I=(4x^2-4x+1,2x^3+x+1)\subset (x-4)$ in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]$. Thus $I\ne (1)$. This shows the desired conclusion.